# Idea for multi-grid in non-uniform mesh

Tags: numerical-methods, multigrid

I am new in multi-grid method. However, all tutorials I read are 2D Poisson equation on uniform mesh. In practices, the mesh is often stretched, but have no idea how to implement multi-grid method on a non-uniform mesh. Could you please give me some hints or recommend some relevant books or tutorials for this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good book someone in my lab is currently using is

**A Multigrid Tutorial: Second Edition**

*By William L. Briggs, Van Emden Henson*